# ngMockE2E intercepting a passthrough

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ngmocke2e

I was wondering if in ngMockE2E there is a way to intercept the response from the server coming through a passthrough. To be prefectly honest I don't have any code examples, because I am not sure what this would look like. I tried this.

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST('localhost/my/test/url').passThrough().respond(
function(method,url,data, something, somethingelse, oneMoreThing){
            console.log(something);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(somethingelse);
            console.log(oneMoreThing);
        });
```

This of course intercepted the **request** to the server and not the **response** from the server, and the only data logged to the console was data that was going to the server, what about the data coming back down? How can I get that data in this context with $httpBackend?